# How to send firebase auth sms in php?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I want to send auth messages to users using PHP but firebase performs this function on the client-side only (e.g. Javascript).
In javascript, I was able to write the following code

```
var phoneNumber = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
.then(function(confirmationResult) {

    console.log(confirmationResult);

}).catch(function(error) {

    console.log(error);

});
```

This code works just fine and sends the verification code (OTP) to the user successfully. But my requirement is to perform this task using PHP. How can I do that? How can I include required firebase files and then how can I run this javascript (or similar) code in PHP?
Is there any way like creating REST APIs or something similar.

Comment: Is this any help? https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/

Comment: The SMS verification messages from Firebase can only be triggered from the client-side SDK. There is no server-side API for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322927/python-api-verified-number-usinf-firebase/65325134#65325134